# Creating virtual environment using venv module through my QGIS Plugin

Tags: python, qgis-plugins

I am trying to create a virtual environment using venv module throuh my plugin main class.

This is what I have tried so far:

```py
import venv
import subprocess

class MyPlugin:

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.create_venv()

    def create_venv(self):
       venv.create('./venv', with_pip=True)
    
    def activate_venv(self):
        venv_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "venv")
        activate_script = os.path.join(venv_dir, "scripts", "activate.bat")
        try:
            subprocess.call([activate_script])
            print("Virtual environment activated")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to activate virtual environment:", e)
    
    def install_package(self):
        self.activate_venv()
        try:
            subprocess.run(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'matplotlib'])
            print("Package installed successfully")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to install package:", e)
```

The error which I am facing is:

1. File not found error, It says that ';venv' dir couldn't be found, but i am trying to create it using `venv.create`
2. Even if the 'venv' dir is created, it doesn't include activate.bat dir in the scripts dir, So couldn't activate the virtual environment.
3. Also i am writing `with_pip=true`, still cannot install libraries using pip.